# What are these pieces from?

Tags: identify-this-game

My parents found these while unpacking. I'm fairly certain they're from a board game of some sort, they're vaguely familiar but I can't place them! 44m diameter. If I had to guess, I'd suspect they're from a game that's aimed at children, but on the interesting end of the spectrum of such games, but I wouldn't count on that. Does anyone recognise them?

[image]

Comment: Look almost like fireball templates to go with a D&D battle mat -- but 44mm is too big for common battle mats.

Comment: How accurate is your measurement? They could be "pogs", but those are normally more like 42mm according to Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It definitely seems a flame token launched by Fire Mario, from McDonald's Happy Meal games.

source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhNh-Ircvg0

Comment: That's why all my Google reverse image searches for it came up with Mario pictures - although none were the fireball token.